# Jquery skip to the last XML child

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML document that contains a list of items:

```
<item>
    <foo>foo!</foo>
    <bar>bar!</bar>
</item>
<item>
    <foo>foo2!</foo>
    <bar>bar2!</bar>
</item>
...
```

Is there a fast and convenient way to get to the last 'item' and parse its foo and bar values without looping through the whole xml?

Comment: Are alert($("item").last().children("foo")); and alert($("item").last().children("bar")); not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the xml is valid (the sample you pasted is not) you could use something like this

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><root><item><foo>foo!</foo><bar>bar!</bar></item><item>    <foo>foo2!</foo>    <bar>bar2!</bar></item></root>';    
var $item = $(xml).find('item:last');

alert($item.find('foo').text());
alert($item.find('bar').text());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/claudioredi/su6vg6bz/)